# javascript on mouse click error

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to get the mousedown mouseup's to work. i need an object to change color on mouse down and on mouseup change back to the original. but for some reason

```
onload = init;

function init() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("buttons")[0].mousedown = function () {
        blue();
    };
    document.getElementsByClassName("buttons")[0].mouseup = function () {
        green();
    };
}

function green() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("buttons")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#360"
}

function blue() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("buttons")[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue"
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event names include `on` prefix: it's `onmousedown` and `onmouseup`:

```
function init() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("buttons")[0].onmousedown = blue;
    document.getElementsByClassName("buttons")[0].onmouseup = green;
}
```

Comment: Also you can rewrite the event handlers:
**`function green() { this.style.backgroundColor = "#360"; }`** and **`function blue() { this.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; }`**

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need javascript to do this?  Why not just use ":active" in CSS?

```
button{background-color: green}
button:active{background-color: blue}
```